# Error: cannot find module error in angularjs docker desktop

Tags: node.js, angularjs, docker

```
angular-angular-1 | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
angular-angular-1 |   throw err;
angular-angular-1 |   ^
angular-angular-1 | 
angular-angular-1 | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/server.js'
angular-angular-1 |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
angular-angular-1 |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
angular-angular-1 |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
angular-angular-1 |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
angular-angular-1 |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
angular-angular-1 |   requireStack: []
angular-angular-1 | }
```

when I try to run docker-compose up in vs code docker desktop shows this error.I don't know what to do with this error?